# JavaScript Form, with validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am currently using html to code a 'form entry'. I am also using a JavaScript validation, to validate the input in of the form. So far, i have the 'name', 'subject' and 'Examination number'. However my validation does not work for my Examination number. for examination number, i want the validation to make sure that the input is only 4 digits, hence i added 'maxlength="4"'. If someone could please help me with this validation to firstly validate the examination number and ensure that the input is four digits, it would be very helpful, thanks

here is my code:

```
<head>

<title>Exam Entry</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function validateForm(e) {

    var result = true;
    var msg="";

    if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="") {
        msg+="You must enter your name \n";
        document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
        document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
        result = false;
    }

    if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="") {
        msg+="You must enter the subject \n";
        document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
        document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
        result = false;
    }

    if (document.ExamEntry.Examination_number.value=="4") {
        msg+="You must enter your Examination number \n";
        document.ExamEntry.Examination_number.focus();
        document.getElementById('Examination_number').style.color="red";
        result = false;
    }

    if (msg != "") {
        alert(msg);
    }

    return result;
}
</script>



</head>

<body>
<h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <table width="60%" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td id="name">Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="subject">Subject</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
        </tr>
            <td id="Examination_number">Examination number</td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="4" name="Examination_number" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            <td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use html5 for this, no javascript required!

Along with the maxlength attribute, include this attribute:

```
pattern="\d{4}"
```

the "pattern" attribute allows you to specify a regex pattern for validating the input.

`\d` is regex meaning "digits". `{4}` is regex meaning repeat exactly 4 times.

The maxlength attribute is actually redundant now, and can be removed since the regex will limit the length of the input on its own.

So overall, your element can look like:

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d{4}" name="Examination_number" />
```

Also just one note: It's also important to keep in mind that client side validation is not equivalent to server-side validation. Anyone with basic webdev knowledge will still be able to post invalid `Examination_Number` values to your server. Your server must be able to validate these values as well.

Comment: do i add pattern="\d{4}" after maxlength? or do i replace maxlength with it? also, what did you mean by post invalid examination number values, does that mean characters that are not digits? if so, how can i change that?

Comment: I edited to respond to your first question. As far as server-side validation goes, that's a rather different question and is specific to whatever server-side language you are using. The general idea, though, is that your server-side code must validate any incoming input on its own - in this case, perform the regex validation, but using your server-side language instead of js.

Comment: have you had any luck with this method?

Comment: i did include this with the regex validation, thank you for your help :0

Comment: it's my pleasure! I'd love the checkmark if you're content with this answer (I'll finally have enough rep to downvote stuff yay!!!)

Answer (score 2):

it's not .value == "4" it's .value.length == 4

Comment: you can, but you don't have to... javascript is type-agnostic (for the most part)

Comment: but, frankly... I would do as some of the others have suggested and use Regex... and handle all the validation cases of each field, ie, not null, length, datatype, etc.

Comment: okay, i added the quotation marks, but i took out the '4', because it would only validate when it was four digits, which i wanted it to validate when there was no input. so this is my new part if (document.ExamEntry.Examination_number.value.length =="") {  , Thank you for you help

Comment: Sorry... I misunderstood... i would really implement a regex solution as suggested below

Answer (score 0):

Use regex... var regex = /^\d{4}$/;

And of course, sorry, you can do it matching the regex... if (regex.test(examinationnumber)) then good..

You could also check the value with isNaN to be sure of getting numbers, like:
 if (!isNaN(examinationnumber)) then good..

To make them alltogether:

```
var regex = /^\d{4}$/;
if (document.ExamEntry.Examination_number.value == "") {
  msg+="You must enter your examination number";
  result = false;
} else if (isNaN(document.ExamEntry.Examination_number.value)) {
    msg+="Examination number should only contain digits";
    result = false;
} else if (!regex.test(document.ExamEntry.Examination_number.value)) {
    msg+="Examination number should contain exactly 4 digits";
    result = false;
}
```

Comment: thanks adam, im definitely going to use this, however i tested it and when there is an error, e.g. i entered 'abcd'for examination number, an error message came up saying it should only be digits, this is good, but when i clicked okay to try another input, it submitted. please help

Comment: What exactly it submitted?

Comment: it submitted the form, as if all the input were correct, this was straight after the error message and didnt allow the user to input another examination number

Comment: Did you not forget to put result = false; at the end of the validation?

Comment: i just added it now, it worked for a few inputs, but its the same for when there is no input, an error message displayed and when i clicked okay, the form was submitted, should i put the result=false; after each message?

Comment: Ah it's in your form.. try onsubmit="return validateForm(this)"

Comment: i added the result=false, after each message, it works!! thanks mate